# How to change value of embeded map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

first of all, I am fairly new to javascript and asp.net. So please bear with me. What I'm trying to do is embedding the map of vesselfinder.com and add a search box. Now I encountered some problem, I'm trying to read the value of the textbox called txtMMIS.Text but when I run the website, I can't pass the value of txtMMIS.Text to variable mmsi in javascript. I have no idea what to do now. I know this will be very simple to other people. Any help will greatly appreciated. Thank to all.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = "900";
    var height = "470";
    var latitude = "19";
    var longitude = "120";
    var zoom = "4";
    var fleet_hide_old_positions = false;
    var names = true;
    var click_to_activate = false;
    var default_maptype = 2;
    var mmsi = '\"' + document.getElementById('<%=txtMMIS.ClientID %>').value + '\"';
    var show_track = true;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.vesselfinder.com/aismap.js">
</script>
```

The textbox code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMMIS" runat="server" value="354925000"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: the textbox code:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMMIS" runat="server" value="354925000"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: anyone? please help.

Comment: aww... nobody help